# How to update a sub-document array fields along with some other fields in Mongodb, Mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Can we update sub-document array fields along with other document fields in Mgo?
If so, please help me with my query.

```
 c := db.C("user")
 colQuerier := bson.M{"email": *olduname}
 change := bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"password":*pwd, "place":*place, "emails.$.received":*received,"emails.$.sent":*sent}}
        err := c.Update(colQuerier, change)
```

My Database Structs are as follows:

```
type Emails struct{
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Received string
    Sent    string  
}

type User   struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Email       string
    Password    string
    Place       string
    Emails     

}
```

I am getting a run time error saying: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: emails.$.received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `emails.received` as `received` is not an array, so you don't need the positional operator `$`:

```
c := db.C("user")
colQuerier := bson.M{"email": *olduname}
change := bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"password":*pwd, "place":*place, "emails.received":*received}}
err := c.Update(colQuerier, change)
```